# Sending big array and receiving wrong order via socket

Tags: c, sockets

I have two programs written in C.
The server tries to send a `uint8_t` array of 360000 bytes and the client needs to receive it.

I received and sent 360000 bytes, but for some reason I don't receive them in the same order.
Both machines are little-endian.

***server*** (Receive is a function with send)

```
#include <stdio.h>  /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <sys/socket.h>  /* for socket(), bind(), and connect() */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /* for sockaddr_in and inet_ntoa() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() */
#include <string.h>     /* for memset*/
#include <unistd.h>     /* for close*/
#include "HandleTCPClient.c"



#define MAXPENDING 5 /* Maximum outstanding connection requests */

void DieWithError(char *errorMessage);  /* Error handling function */
void HandleTCPClient(int clntSocket);  /* TCP client handling function */

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int servSock;                         /* Socket descriptor for server */
int clntSock;                         /* Socket descriptor for client */
struct sockaddr_in ServAddr;      /* Local address */
struct sockaddr_in ClntAddr;      /* Client address */
unsigned short ServPort;          /* Server port */
unsigned int clntLen;                 /* Length of client address data structure */


if (argc != 2)      /* Test for correct number of arguments */
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <Server Port>\n", argv[0]) ;
    exit(1);
}

ServPort = atoi(argv[1]);  /* First arg: local port */

/* Create socket for incoming connections */
if ((servSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    DieWithError( "socket () failed") ;

/* Construct local address structure */
memset(&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));   // Zero out structure 
ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                // Internet address family 
ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY); // Any incoming interface 
ServAddr.sin_port = htons(ServPort);      // Local port 

/* Bind to the local address */
if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr *)&ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr)) < 0)
    DieWithError ( "bind () failed");


// Mark the socket so it will listen for incoming connections 
if (listen(servSock, MAXPENDING) < 0)
    DieWithError("listen() failed") ;

int count = 0;
for (;;) // Run forever 
    {
        count++;
        /* Set the size of the in-out parameter */
        clntLen = sizeof(ClntAddr);

        /* Wait for a client to connect */
        if ((clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &ClntAddr, &clntLen)) < 0)
            DieWithError("accept() failed");

        /* clntSock is connected to a client! */
        printf ("%sConnection Number: %d                                                                     :-)%s \n" ,"\033[1m\033[42m" ,  count , "\033[0m");
        printf("Handling client %s\n", inet_ntoa(ClntAddr.sin_addr));
            getchar();
        HandleTCPClient (clntSock);
        printf ("Finished Handling client %s\n", inet_ntoa(ClntAddr.sin_addr));
    }
}

void DieWithError(char const *errorMessage)
{
    printf ("%s" , "\033[1m\033[31m" ); // Bold RED
    perror(errorMessage);
    printf ("%s" , "\033[0m" ); // Black
    exit(1);
}
```

***SERVER - Call to Handle TCP client (main part of the function)***

```
array Data[6];
    int totalRecvMsgSize = 0, recvMsgSize = 0;
printf ("RCVBUFSIZE:%d\n" , RCVBUFSIZE);
//printf("%sInside the recv%s\n" , "\033[1m\033[46m" , "\033[0m");
while((totalRecvMsgSize <= (RCVBUFSIZE - 1) ))
// we need a loop since recv retrives only the data curntley available.
    {   
        //printf("%sInside the recv while loop%s\n" , "\033[1m\033[45m" , "\033[0m");
    // Receive message from client
    if ((recvMsgSize = recv(clntSocket, Buffer, RCVBUFSIZE - totalRecvMsgSize, 0)) < 0)
        DieWithError("recv() failed") ;
    else if (recvMsgSize == 0)
        {
            printf("(case is recvMsgSize == 0 ) ----> totalRecvMsgSize = %d\n", totalRecvMsgSize);
            break;
        }
    else // if recvMsgSize > 0
        totalRecvMsgSize += recvMsgSize;

    }
Data[DataCounter].elementNumber = RCVBUFSIZE_SOURCE;
Data[DataCounter].colus = 1024; //step
Data[DataCounter].rows = 357; // rows
Data[DataCounter].key = DataCounter;
shiftData (Data);
```

***Client Send function***

```
void TcpClient ( char *servIP , unsigned short echoServPort , array_t *arrayData)
{

int i = 0;
for (i = 0 ; i < 365568 ; i++)
    {
        Data->arrayData[i] = i;
        printf ("%d " ,Data->array[i]);
    }
printf("\n");
//***************************************************************************************************************

//*****************************Create a socket and Establish connection to server *******************************

int sock;                           //Socket descriptor 
struct sockaddr_in ServAddr;    //Echo server address            
int bytesRcvd, totalBytesRcvd;      //Bytes read in single recv()
                                    //and total bytes read      
// Create a reliable, stream socket using TCP 
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    DieWithError("socket () failed") ;

// Construct the server address structure 
memset(&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));  /* Zero out structure */
ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;               /* Internet address family */
ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(servIP);/* Server IP address */
ServAddr.sin_port = htons(echoServPort);    /* Server port */

// Establish the connection to the server 
if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr)) < 0)
    DieWithError("connect () failed") ;

printf ("I am in Send\n");
size_t sent_total = 0;
int sent_now = 0;
sent_now = send(sockId, buffer + sent_total, len - sent_total, 0);
    //printf("After sent(), sent now = %d\n" , sent_now);
    if (sent_now == -1)
        DieWithError("send() failed or connection closed prematurely");

printf ("send requested = %zu, sent = %zu\n", len, sent_total);


printf("\n"); // Print a final linefeed
```

I looked in the man page and in different forums and didn't find anything. 
* I tried to not to put everything because it is to long!

Comment: There is not enough here to see what might be going on.  Please update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you don't adjust the address `Buffer` between `recv` calls, you are continually overwriting the same space.  If you do adjust the address `Buffer`, you should show the code that does that.  You also don't show the code tracking how many bytes are read in each `recv()` call, so there really isn't any chance of us helping you.

Comment: We would especially like to see you read and write the send and receive buffers and the type definitions involved.

Comment: Are you sending over tcp or udp? Did you verified that the sending sends everything? Please post some more code, we actually cannot tell you more.

Comment: I update the question, is it better or just to put all the both side codes?

Comment: `arr` appears to be a type, not a variable name. Does `arr->array` even compile?

Comment: Note that your code only checks for an error from `send` or `recv`; it does not check for short writes or reads.  You probably need to use looping code to keep going until all the expected data has been read.  You also need to ensure that you're writing from the correct location in the buffer, and reading into the correct location in the buffer.  None of that is clearly implemented in the code I see.

Comment: Tomorrow I will post the all code. I a man using tcp socket. I do recieve all the data but the order is wrong

Comment: I added more code to the question. If you need i will add more please tell me.